# HAProxy - Partial SSL Offloading

Tags: haproxy

Currently, I'm using tcp mode to redirect SSL traffic to two backend nodes where the certs are loaded and processed.  This is working as expecting, and in apache with SNI I can process the necessary domains.

For one of these domains, I have a need to move it to a different backend and server.  My question - is it possible to get this setup in haproxy within the same frontend ip / port?  I do not want to load ALL the certs into HAProxy - but it would be fine to load just the cert for the site that needs to point at a different backend.

Basically, can I run something like this without needed to load all ssl certs into haproxy?

```
    acl host_mysite hdr(host) -i mysite.example.com
```

Update.  Here are the existing config sections:

```
frontend http_frontend
    bind :::80 v4v6
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    default_backend http_backend
    acl host_mysite hdr(host) -i mysite.example.com
    use_backend http_backend2 if host_mysite

backend http_backend
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    default-server inter 4s rise 3 fall 2
    fullconn 20000
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
    server server1 192.168.192.1:80 maxconn 10000 check
    server server2 192.168.192.2:80 maxconn 10000 check

backend http_backend2
    mode http
    default-server inter 4s rise 3 fall 2
    fullconn 20000
    server server3 192.168.192.3:80 maxconn 10000 check

frontend ssl_frontend
    bind :::443 v4v6
    mode tcp
    default_backend ssl_backend

backend ssl_backend
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    default-server inter 4s rise 3 fall 2
    fullconn 20000
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server server1 192.168.192.1:443 maxconn 10000 check
    server server2 192.168.192.2:443 maxconn 10000 check
```

Comment: How is HAProxy currently making routing decisions? Or are 2 the existing backends identical and simply load balanced?

Comment: I added the current config i'm playing with so you can take a look.

Comment: So, as describedn you're not terminating SSL at this machine, you're just passing TCP data, uninterpreted, to the back-ends, which are terminating the SSL.  The next question is whether the new backend can be equipped the same.  If true, the configuration here will be simpler, and you don't need any certs here at all, you'll do something similar to `use_backend some-other-backend if { req_ssl_sni -i example.com }`.  If you want HAProxy to terminate the SSL, it requires a loopback between an extra pair of `frontend/backend` or `listen`.  Which config are you looking to do?

Comment: In the ideal world, haproxy would not do any termination, and the backends would handle it.  I just wasn't sure if/how to set that up.  I'll read some more on the req_ssl_sni option